# How to force bottom Navigation to start nested graph navigation from the startDestination?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a simple toy app that works on one mainActivity. It has a bottom navigation bar with separate nested graphs. For instance, the navigation graph "notification" has an additional destination to settings. If I move to "notification" >>> "settings" >>>> to "home"/"dashboard" nested navigation and get back to "notification", it will show the most recent state of nested graph, which is "settings".

**How to make the bottom navigation to get to the startDestination, which is "notification", after I double click "notification" menu item**? For instance, the first time I click "notification" it retrieves "settings", if I click the same "notification" item in the bottom navigation, it will get me to the startDestination "notification".

activity_main.xml

```
package com.example.myvagtest;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.myvagtest.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_nested3,R.id.navigation_nested2,R.id.navigation_nested1).build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }

}
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_nested1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_nested2"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_dashboard" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_nested3"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_notifications" />

</menu>
```

navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_nested1">

    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/navigation_nested1"
        app:startDestination="@id/navigation_home">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
            android:name="com.example.myvagtest.ui.home.HomeFragment"
            android:label="@string/title_home"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    </navigation>

    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/navigation_nested2"
        app:startDestination="@id/navigation_dashboard">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
            android:name="com.example.myvagtest.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
            android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />
    </navigation>

    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/navigation_nested3"
        app:startDestination="@id/navigation_notifications"
        >
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
            android:name="com.example.myvagtest.ui.SettingsFragment"
            android:label="settings"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_navigation_settings_to_navigation_notifications"
                app:destination="@id/navigation_notifications" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
            android:name="com.example.myvagtest.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
            android:label="@string/title_notifications"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_navigation_notifications_to_navigation_settings"
                app:destination="@id/navigation_settings" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_navigation_notifications_pop"
                app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_notifications"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        </fragment>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_nested3_self"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_notifications"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_notifications"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </navigation>

</navigation>
```

Update:

```
 public void bottomNavigationReselection() {
        navView.setOnItemReselectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemReselectedListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.home_navigation) {
                    navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_home_navigation);
                } else if (id == R.id.explore_navigation){
                    navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_explore);
                } else if (id == R.id.library_navigation){
                    navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_library);
                } else if (id == R.id.profile_navigation) {
                    navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_navigation_profile);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

is enough to refresh main destinations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer in Kotlin, that worked for me.

In Parent Fragment or Activity

```
navView.setOnItemReselectedListener {
            navigateWithOptions(it.itemId)
        }
```

When item reselected you need to clear back stack and navigate to first fragment in stack (start destination).

```
private fun navigateWithOptions(idToNavigationInto: Int) {
    navController.currentDestination?.let {
        NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(it.id, true).build().also { options ->
            navController.navigate(
                idToNavigationInto,
                null,
                options
            )
        }
    }
}
```